# Does a file need to be in HDFS in order to use it in distributed cache?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distributed-cache

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file:/path/to/my.jar, expected: hdfs://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

if I try to add a local file to distributed cache in hadoop.  When the file is on HDFS, I don't get this error (obviously, since it's using the expected FS).  Is there a way to use a local file in distributed cache without first copying it to hdfs?  Here is a code snippet:

```
Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);
Path dependency = fs.makeQualified(new Path("/local/path/to/my.jar");
DistributedCache.addArchiveToClassPath(path, conf);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It has to be in HDFS first. I'm going to go out on a limb here, but I think it is because the file is "pulled" to the local distributed cache by the slaves, not pushed. Since they are pulled, they have no way to access that local path.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can put anything on the distributed cache without it being in HDFS first. All Hadoop jobs use input/output path in relation to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

File can be either in local system, hdfs, S3 or other cluster also. You need to specify as

-files hdfs://   if the file is in hdfs

by default it assumes local file system.